# pip install -r requirements.txt not installing everything

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtualenv

I recently installed Mojave and then I had to upgrade my VirtualBox & vagrant afterwards. I am currently having an issue installing the requirements.txt in my venv.

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 24)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 24))
```

Answer (score 0):

deleted **pkg-resources==0.0.0**
I used this instead:
pip install --user -r requirements.txt